# Hacking a trail camera

Tags: camera, hacking

A quick warning, I have no prior knowledge in electronics. I don't even know if what I'm asking is doable.

Here is the idea. I was given an old refurbished Reconnyx Hyperfire 2 camera trap. The flash doesn't work anymore but the logic seems fine.

I would like to reuse it by bypassing the camera from the board and using my own DSLR camera, basically turning it into a fancy IR detector.

To connect to the camera, I will be using a 2.5mm jack. One wire for the shutter and the other one for the ground.

I have no idea where to start with this. I guess I should start by buying a multi-meter and try to figure out where I can plug my cables.

I don't know if it can help, but here is the board:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think this circuit is suitable for what you are asking for. It seem to have a full-blown  integrated camera interface. The whole circuit pretty much *is a camera* itself, while you are asking a simple motion detector switch.

Comment: Well. The interest with this board is that it is easily programmable. If possible I would like to take full advantage of that. Keeping the whole camera interface and (simply) by-passing the camera module. Do you think it isn't possible ?

Comment: It should be possible, but the question is the amount of the effort and the suitability of the chosen starting point. In my opinion it is not suitable, and the effort reverse engineering it is disproportional.

Comment: Alright. Then thanks a lot for your help !
I thought that it would be an easy task. But if you think it won't, then I will settle for a different approach.
Thanks again !

Comment: If the flash still generates a signal level (maybe the circuit works but the bulb is burned out?), perhaps you can adapt that as a trigger for your external camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to do this without much reverse engineering. I can think of several solutions that do not require many tools or part. However it will require some basic electronics knowledge. But this is at a level that it would be a decent "Hello World" project for electronics - with the following hints as orientation. So I bet you could do it but it will require some learning effort.

Basically you only need to find a signal that changes it's state (voltage) only when the trap is triggered. This can actually be done by the same circuit that should later trigger your camera. I will describe the concept for the solution first then I will show that there is a wide range of implementations for this concept.

*Concept*

- To the trap signal you attach a circuit that acts as a latch. Once the trap is triggered it will stay in that state - this helps to trigger your camera reliably even when the signal from the trap is too fast or too short.
- Depending on implementation the latch should have an adjustable threshold - the voltage at which the latch "latches".
- From the latch you need an actuator that triggers the camera.
- Connect the remote control cable from your camera to the actuator. Usually the actuator needs to short two signals of the control cable together (this depends on the camera). If you can not get a remote control cable with separate wires for the camera trigger, then this project will get too complex in my opinion.
- To arm the camera again the latch needs to be reset by a mechanism.

*Implementation*

These are options how you could build that concept. The circuits can be build on a breadboard. Soldering the final result is recommended, unless your camera trap sits indoors and never moves.

- A bipolar transistor with resistors: The least robust solution but also the easiest to build. It will not act as a latch so finding the right signal is more important. The signal from the trap is connected through a resistor to the base of the transistor. The collector of the transistor connects the positive wire on the control cable to the ground wire - when the signal from the trap is positive. The transistor can control a relay instead to isolate the camera from your circuit. This is also the recommended output for all other implementations.
- Discrete Latch: A latch can be build with transistors or logic gates. Or you can get a integrated circuit (IC) that is already a latch. The latch needs to be reset by a timing circuit. This can likely be done by an abundantly available "555" timer IC, though I never really used that one.
- Microcontroller / Arduino: the most flexible option, buying an Arduino or similar probably gives you an easier start. The signal from your trap goes to the ADC of your microcontroller. The threshold is set in the programm. The latch and reset can be coded as well. The output of the MCU goes to the transistor output above.
- I want all the pain / Assembly: The program for this task is not too complex. You can challenge yourself by writing it in Assembly, which is about the most direct way to write a program for a microcontroller. If you manage that, you will gain important expertise that quite a few programmers nowadays lack.

*Finding the right signal*

- Check that your circuit triggers when you connect an AA Battery as its input signal.
- Connect the ground of your circuit to the ground of the camera trap.
- Use the wire for your input signal and press it to one of the metal contacs on the pcb.Preferably connections that go to the onboard camera or flash.
- Force the camera trap to trigger.
- Does your circuit triggers your camera?
- If not repeat this with another contact.

*Hints*

- Whenever you connect a signal between two circuits, you also need to make a connection for the return current and common reference - this is usually done by connecting the grounds of the two circuits to each other.
- If you mess things up you might damage your camera. Check the wiring on the remote cable and use a relay between your circuit and the cable.
- A multimeter and a very simple oscilloscope can help a lot in building and understanding whats happening.